# Liferay: huge DLFileRank table

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, usage-statistics

I have a Liferay 6.2 server that has been running for years and is starting to take a lot of database space, despite limited actual content.

```
Table           Size   Number of rows
--------------------------------------
DLFileRank      5 GB   16 million
DLFileEntry     90 MB  60,000
JournalArticle  2 GB   100,000
```

The size of the `DLFileRank` table sounds to me as abnormally big (if it is totally normal please let me know).

While the file ranking feature of Liferay is nice to have, we would not really mind resetting it if it halves the size of the database.

**Question**: Would a `DELETE * FROM DLFileRank` be safe? (stop Liferay, run that SQL command, maybe set `dl.file.rank.enabled=false` in `portal-ext.properties`, start Liferay again)
Is there any better way to do it?

*Bonus if there is a way to keep recent ranking data and throw away only the old data (not a strong requirement).*

Answer (score 1):

Wow. According to the [documentation here](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> rank), I'd not have expected the number of entries to be so high - did you configure those values differently?

> Set the interval in minutes on how often CheckFileRankMessageListener
>   will run to check for and remove file ranks in excess of the maximum
>   number of file ranks to maintain per user per file. Defaults:
>
> ```
> dl.file.rank.check.interval=15
> ```
>
> Set this to true to enable file rank for document library files.
>   Defaults:
>
> ```
> dl.file.rank.enabled=true
> ```
>
> Set the maximum number of file ranks to maintain per user per file.
>   Defaults:
>
> ```
> dl.file.rank.max.size=5
> ```

And according to the [implementation of CheckFileRankMessageListener](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/messaging/CheckFileRankMessageListener.java), it should be enough to just trigger `DLFileRankLocalServiceUtil.checkFileRanks()` yourself (e.g. through the scripting console). Why you accumulate that large number of files is beyond me...

As you might know, I can never be quoted by stating that direct database manipulation is the way to go - in fact I refuse thinking about the problem from that way.